# Can AngularJS trigger $watch on one URL when data is updated on another URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wondering if I can trigger `$watch` for changes in the database when they are not caused by the Users actions on their current page.

For example, **the controller**:

```
.MesgCtrl(...)
$scope.data = {'name': 'Tim', 'visits': 0};

$scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log("$watch triggered");
  });
```

For example, on the **template.html** I have:

```
<ul ng-repeat="d in data">
  <li>{{d}}</li>
</ul>
```

A different REST endpoint URL gets POST requests for the visits, and updates them in the database when they occur.  I'd like for the visit counts to update on *template.html* for the User to see when they are updated in the database. But, so far, I have only been able to get `$watch` to work when calling `$resource.save()` to update *visits* from the same AngularJS Controller URL, and not from a different URL.

Comment: Not without setting up an ajax poll or socket connection with server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need two ways communication, like updates on a client when someone else visits a page, you could use a librairie like socket.io http://socket.io/ which visit to every connected socket).

You could also add a timer to request like every 30sec the server and get an update of your visit counter (use `$interval` for this).

Use `$timeout` if you only want to request it once after a certain amount of time has elapsed.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I ended up using `$interval`.  I think socket.io is a good option, but my backend is *python/django* and socket.io is built for node.js, so it's harder to get it to all work together.  I will add my specific code in an answer below.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$interval` worked to schedule data refreshes, and pull through changes to the Web Browser Client.  Here is the code I used:

```
conciergeControllers.controller('MessageCtrl',
    function MessageCtrl($scope, $stateParams, $interval, Message, GuestMessages) {
        $scope.messages = {};

        $scope.getGuest = function(GuestMessages, $stateParams, $scope) {
            GuestMessages.get({
                id: $stateParams.guestId
            }, function(response) {
                $scope.guest = response;
                $scope.to = response.phone_number;
                $scope.messages = response.messages;

                // test
                console.log('Guest:', $scope.guest);
            });
        }
        // populate initial context without a delay
        $scope.getGuest(GuestMessages, $stateParams, $scope);

        $interval(function(){ $scope.getGuest(GuestMessages, $stateParams, $scope); }, 5000);
    }
);
```